# Google map is displaying only when its size get resized

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am loading google map in my webpage with some width and height.Here is my code:

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
        });
        //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
        /*$(window).resize(function() {           
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
          });*/
        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
          drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
          drawingControl: true,
          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: ['polygon', 'polyline']
          },

          circleOptions: {
            strokeColor: '#00DB00',
            fillColor: 'green'      
          }

        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
       }
```

style:

```
#map{
width:500px;
height:300px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="cl col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

When I load the page,map is displaying like this

[image]

After resizing the map its displaying correctly.
[image]

What is the problem here?

Comment: @downvoter what is the reason to down vote my question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `drawingManager.setMap(map);` at the end of your `initMap` function.

Comment: No actually I missed here only.